# Synchronise CRM users with AD

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm

When you create a new user through the UI, it will retrieve all details from Active Directory once you've entered a user name (job title, phone, email etc..) which is great but it only seems to work when the user name is changed in the UI.

I'm importing >100 users into a new CRM system, how can I trigger this synchronisation across all of them in bulk? Without browsing through 100 user records and making minor tweaks to the user name field.

Comment: Have you looked into whether this tool would work with your version of CRM? https://updatecrm2011fromad.codeplex.com/

Comment: Great find, thanks @Henrik. In my particular case I'm using CRM 2015 so I'll need to test if it works, but Microsoft haven't changed the service endpoint (which I suspect it's using) very much so there's a good chance. If you'd like to make this into a real answer, the bounties yours unless someone can tell me how to utilise the OOTB features or has a reputable tool that's already been tested in 2015.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have left it as an answer but would also like to see if anyone has other methods.

Answer (score 2):

The following command line tool can be used for updating all out of sync users with the newest data from Active Directory:
[Update CRM 2011 Users From AD Tool](https://updatecrm2011fromad.codeplex.com/)

It is not clear if the tool would also work for CRM 2015.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a program that reads all CRM users and then do a search in the AD to see what has been changed to update the CRM. I have written a service that does that once when a customer wanted to have a synch with the AD, that ran once every six hours or so.

Comment: The thing is, this functionality has come out of the box since CRM 2011, probably earlier, it's just inaccessible AFAIK. I know I can write a service to do it (or more likely a plugin) but this will take time I do not have.